# Parsing a list of strings in ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

I have this list:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
 "ansible_facts": {
    "servs": [
        "Is active: Yes\nHost Name: northrend\n Ip Address: 192.168.1.12",
        "Is active: Yes\nHost Name: pandaria \n IP Address: 192.168.1.30"
             ]
},
```

I've been trying to parse this list to extract the value of "Host name" but I just keep on getting the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
 "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ servs | regex_search('Host Name: (.)+\n'),multiline=True) }}): expected string or buffer"
}
```

This is what I tried:

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        output: {{ servs | regex_search('Host Name: (.)+\n'), multiline=True) }}
```

How do you properly parse the contents of this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list *servs* is nearly valid YAML. Only the indentation of the attribute 'Ip Address' is wrong. One space shifted to the right. If you manage to get rid of this space, e.g.

```yaml
    servs:
      - "Is active: Yes\nHost Name: northrend\nIp Address: 192.168.1.12"
      - "Is active: Yes\nHost Name: pandaria \nIP Address: 192.168.1.30"
```

the situation would be trivial. Simply convert the list of strings to a list of dictionaries, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        servs_list: "{{ servs_list|d([]) + [item|from_yaml] }}"
      loop: "{{ servs }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  servs_list:
  - Host Name: northrend
    Ip Address: 192.168.1.12
    Is active: true
  - Host Name: pandaria
    IP Address: 192.168.1.30
    Is active: true
```

If you can't fix the indentation parse the data on your own. The task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        servs_list: "{{ servs_list|d([]) + [item|
                                            regex_replace(regex, replace)|
                                            from_yaml] }}"
      loop: "{{ servs }}"
      vars:
        regex: '\n '
        replace: '\n'
```

Get the output

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        output: "{{ servs_list|map(attribute='Host Name')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  output:
  - northrend
  - Pandaria
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using this one since it perfectly suited what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple errors here:

- `regex_search` works on strings, not lists. So you need to apply it to each list element.
- Your regex creates one group for each character in your hostname. The group should be `(.+)`.
- You are returning the whole match (including `Host Name:`) and not just the name itself. You need to specify which matching group to return.

I guess the list is from the output of some script or in some file. It would be a lot better to have it as `json` or `yaml` and then use [`from_json` or `from_yaml`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json).

If you want to keep it like that, you need to do this:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    servs:
      - |
        Is active: Yes
        Host Name: northrend
        Ip Address: 192.168.1.12
      - |
        Is active: Yes
        Host Name: pandaria
        IP Address: 192.168.1.30
  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ servs }}"
    - set_fact:
        output: "{{ servs | map('regex_search', 'Host Name: (.+)\n', '\\1') | list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ output }}"
```

This is the output:

```
TASK [debug] ************
ok: [local] => {
    "msg": [
        "Is active: Yes\nHost Name: northrend\nIp Address: 192.168.1.12\n",
        "Is active: Yes\nHost Name: pandaria\nIP Address: 192.168.1.30\n"
    ]
}

TASK [set_fact] ***************
ok: [local]

TASK [debug] ************
ok: [local] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "northrend"
        ],
        [
            "pandaria"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This information helped a lot. I got the list from dotwalking json output and then converting it to a list.

Comment: @pilipeet If it helped you, please consider upvoting it clicking the upwards-pointing triangle left of my post. You should also accept the answer that answers your question in the best way.